# Closed tab by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking at one of the example that allows us to create a slide out tab. It looks amazing and works fine. My only concern is how can I set the tab behaviour as closed by default? [Please see the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lpdykhx/67/)

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.tabSlideOut = function(callerSettings) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      tabHandle: '.handle',
      speed: 300,
      action: 'click',
      tabLocation: 'left',
      topPos: '200px',
      leftPos: '20px',
      fixedPosition: false,
      positioning: 'absolute',
      pathToTabImage: null,
      imageHeight: null,
      imageWidth: null,
      onLoadSlideOut: false
    }, callerSettings || {});

    settings.tabHandle = $(settings.tabHandle);
    var obj = this;
    if (settings.fixedPosition === true) {
      settings.positioning = 'fixed';
    } else {
      settings.positioning = 'absolute';
    }

    //ie6 doesn't do well with the fixed option
    if (document.all && !window.opera && !window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      settings.positioning = 'absolute';
    }



    //set initial tabHandle css

    if (settings.pathToTabImage != null) {
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'background': 'url(' + settings.pathToTabImage + ') no-repeat',
        'width': settings.imageWidth,
        'height': settings.imageHeight
      });
    }

    settings.tabHandle.css({
      'display': 'block',
      'textIndent': '-99999px',
      'outline': 'none',
      'position': 'absolute'
    });

    obj.css({
      'line-height': '1',
      'position': settings.positioning
    });


    var properties = {
      containerWidth: parseInt(obj.outerWidth(), 10) + 'px',
      containerHeight: parseInt(obj.outerHeight(), 10) + 'px',
      tabWidth: parseInt(settings.tabHandle.outerWidth(), 10) + 'px',
      tabHeight: parseInt(settings.tabHandle.outerHeight(), 10) + 'px'
    };

    //set calculated css
    if (settings.tabLocation === 'top' || settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
      obj.css({
        'left': settings.leftPos
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'right': 0
      });
    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'top') {
      obj.css({
        'top': '-' + properties.containerHeight
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'bottom': '-' + properties.tabHeight
      });
    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
      obj.css({
        'bottom': '-' + properties.containerHeight,
        'position': 'fixed'
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'top': '-' + properties.tabHeight
      });

    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'left' || settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
      obj.css({
        'height': properties.containerHeight,
        'top': settings.topPos
      });

      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'top': 0
      });
    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'left') {
      obj.css({
        'left': '-' + properties.containerWidth
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'right': '-' + properties.tabWidth
      });
    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
      obj.css({
        'right': '-' + properties.containerWidth
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'left': '-' + properties.tabWidth
      });

      $('html').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
    }

    //functions for animation events

    settings.tabHandle.click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    var slideIn = function() {

      if (settings.tabLocation === 'top') {
        obj.animate({
          top: '-' + properties.containerHeight
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideIn).removeClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'left') {
        obj.animate({
          left: '-' + properties.containerWidth
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideIn).removeClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
        obj.animate({
          right: '-' + properties.containerWidth
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideIn).removeClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
        obj.animate({
          bottom: '-' + properties.containerHeight
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideIn).removeClass('open');
      }

    };

    var slideOut = function() {

      if (settings.tabLocation == 'top') {
        obj.animate({
          top: '-3px'
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideOut).addClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'left') {
        obj.animate({
          left: '-3px'
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideOut).addClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'right') {
        obj.animate({
          right: '-3px'
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideOut).addClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'bottom') {
        obj.animate({
          bottom: '-3px'
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideOut).addClass('open');
      }

      settings.onSlideOut
    };

    var clickScreenToClose = function() {
      obj.click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      });

      $(document).click(function() {
        slideIn();
      });
    };

    var clickAction = function() {
      settings.tabHandle.click(function(event) {
        if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
          slideIn();
        } else {
          slideOut();
        }
      });

      clickScreenToClose();
    };

    var hoverAction = function() {
      obj.hover(

        function() {
          slideOut();
        },

        function() {
          slideIn();
        });

      settings.tabHandle.click(function(event) {
        if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
          slideIn();
        }
      });
      clickScreenToClose();

    };

    var slideOutOnLoad = function() {
      slideIn();
      setTimeout(slideOut, 500);
    };

    //choose which type of action to bind
    if (settings.action === 'click') {
      clickAction();
    }

    if (settings.action === 'hover') {
      hoverAction();
    }

    if (settings.onLoadSlideOut) {
      slideOutOnLoad();
    };

  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {

  $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle', //class of the element that will become your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'http://s14.postimg.org/pugbeet4h/cs_slide_out.png', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
    imageHeight: '217px', //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
    imageWidth: '33px', //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
    tabLocation: 'right', //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 500, //speed of animation
    action: 'click', //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '200px', //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
    leftPos: '20px', //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
    fixedPosition: false //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
  });

  $('.slide-out-div > .handle').click();

});
```

Comment: Thats a lot of js for something that could be created using CSS and a simple class toggle function in jQuery!

Comment: At least it should have been simplified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="slide-out-div open">
```

Add the class `open` to your div. 
Check [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lpdykhx/71/), it's now closed by default.